# Wait for Server response before letting client enter another message

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey i am writing an application. I am asking the client to enter certain message depending upon the message received i am sending data back to client from server. What happens is when user enters data from client side, before the response comes the client prints one more time "Enter message"... I am using readline and net module of node.js. Here's my code:

```
var server = net.createServer(   //My server side code which sends response.
function(socket){
    console.log("Client connection...");


    socket.on('end', function(){
        console.log("Client disconnected...");

    });

    socket.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(" Received: ", data.toString());

        a=data.toString();

        if(a=="lookupByLastName Smith") //json data send if client sends this
        {
            arr= employees.lookupByLastName('Smith');
            socket.write("Data"+JSON.stringify(arr));
        }




    });

    socket.write("Hello from server");
});
```

//Client Side code:

```
 var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
 });

var readMessage = function(client) {
        rl.question("Enter Message: ", function (line){
        client.write(line);//enter message appears twice before server res.                    
        if (line == "bye")
            client.end();
        else
            readMessage(client);
   });
};

 var client = net.connect({port:3000},
   function(){
      console.log("Connected to server");
      readMessage(client);
    });

client.on('end', function(){
    console.log("Client disconnected...");
    return;
  });

  client.on('data', function(data){
   console.log("\n --Received:", data.toString());  
 });
```

[Check the second message "Enter message" it shouldn't appear second time till server responds back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVrE7.png).So help required in solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask user input when data has been received from server.

In the following example, I also added some timeout for the server hello message and when the server is not responding to client message for 4sec :

```
var readline = require('readline');
var net = require('net');

var port = 3000;

var helloTimeout;
var responseTimeout;
var timeout = 4000;

var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

var readMessage = function(client) {
    rl.question("Enter Message: ", function(line) {
        client.write(line); //enter message appears twice before server res.                    
        if (line == "bye") {
            client.end();
        } else {
            responseTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('not response from server for ' + timeout + "ms");
                client.emit("wait_for_input");
            }, timeout);
        }
    });
};

var client = net.connect({ port: port },
    function() {
        console.log("Connected to server");
        helloTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('no hello received for ' + timeout + "ms, closing ...");
            client.end();
        }, timeout);
    });

client.on('end', function() {
    console.log("Client disconnected...");
    rl.close();
});

client.on('wait_for_input', function() {
    readMessage(client);
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    clearTimeout(helloTimeout);
    clearTimeout(responseTimeout);
    console.log("\n --Received:", data.toString());
    client.emit("wait_for_input");
});
```

I've created another event to `client` called `wait_for_input` triggered only after data comes from server (after computation of this data) and when the client doesn't receive response from server for more than 4sec after the user has typed some command

Comment: Well have you  solved the problem with just timeout or is there any other way. Secondly server code would remain same as i posted. I didnt get your logic.

Comment: Forget the timeout, the user is asked for input only after data is received from server. After input is typed, the client won't do anything until data response comes from server etc.